# Create PDF Document using Oracle XML Publisher APIs

Tags: java, oracle, rest

I am trying to generate a PDF document using Rest API. BI Publisher libraries used:
   fnd_i18n.jar
   xdocore.jar
   xmlparserv2-904.jar
   collections.jar
   i18nAPI_v3.jar
   versioninfo.jar
Exception:

```
{  
    "timestamp": 1573476521580,  
    "status": 500,  
    "error": "Internal Server Error",  
    "exception": "java.lang.IllegalAccessError",  
    "message": "tried to access method oracle.apps.fnd.i18n.common.util.DateFormatMaskConverter.getJavaDateFormatFromOracle(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Locale;Z)Ljava/lang/String; from class oracle.apps.fnd.i18n.common.util.FormatMaskUtil",  
    "path": "/runXMLPub/runXML"  
}
```

Code:

```
try{  
     DataProcessor dataProcessor = new DataProcessor();  
     dataProcessor.setDataTemplate("/tmp/XXONT_SO_ACK.xml");  
     Hashtable parameters = new Hashtable();  
     parameters.put("P_ORDER_NUMBER","2000010477");  
     parameters.put("P_ORDER_LINE_ID","");  
     dataProcessor.setParameters(parameters);  
     dataProcessor.setConnection(jdbcConnection);  
     dataProcessor.setOutput("/tmp/XXONT_SO_ACK_OUT.xml");  
     dataProcessor.processData();  
     RTFProcessor rtfProcessor = new RTFProcessor("/tmp/XXONT_SO_ACK.rtf");   
     rtfProcessor.setOutput("/tmp/XXONT_SO_ACK.xsl");  
     rtfProcessor.process();  
     FOProcessor processor = new FOProcessor();  
     processor.setData("/tmp/XXONT_SO_ACK_OUT.xml");  
     processor.setTemplate("/tmp/XXONT_SO_ACK.xsl");  
     processor.setOutput("/tmp/XXONT_SO_ACK.pdf");    
     processor.setOutputFormat(FOProcessor.FORMAT_PDF);  
     processor.generate();  
     fProcessor.process();  
} catch (Exception e)  
   {  
       System.out.println("Exception..." );  
       e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Any help to resolve this issue will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've not done this before with Oracle XML Publisher API's, however, its obvious from the exception that it can't get access to something that it needs indicating a configuration issue or a permissions issue.  Did you build this API call or did you grab it from a website already built?  I ask this question to help us in which direction to go: is it a config issue or is it a coding issue?

Comment: I have created a gradle project in eclipse workspace and compiled the code, deployed the war on weblogic server. The exception is coming in the initialization of DataProcessor object.
 DataProcessor dataProcessor = new DataProcessor();

Comment: It looks like its throwing the exception past that object instantiation "oracle.apps.fnd.i18n.common.util.FormatMaskUtil" but can't be certain.  Can you comment out the rest of the function calls after "dataProcessor = new DataProcessor();" and see if it still gets the exception?  Need to isolate where its really happening..."divide and conquer"